# 2D Random Walk: Average distance after 2 steps

Tags: probability, random-walk

A simulation of 50,000 iterations gives the average distance after a 2-step (unit step) random walk on a 2 dimensional plane, which is around 1.27. But how can one mathematically prove this?

Any insight is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you just walking on the usual lattice?  Makes a significant difference in the result.

Comment: Are your steps always north, east, south, or west, or can they be in any direction? My answer assumes any direction, while kimchi lover assumed the other.

Comment: The question assumes walking in any direction. I'm sorry for the confusion and thank you to anyone who contributed ideas/thoughts/comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the coordinates so the first step is to $(1,0)$.  If the second step is at angle $\theta$, the end point is then $(1+\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$.  The distance from the origin is then $\sqrt{(1+\cos \theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{2+2\cos \theta}$  The average of this over $\theta$ is 
$$\frac 1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2+2\cos \theta}d\theta=\frac 8{2\pi}\approx 1.2732$$

Comment: I think this is more likely to be what the OP had in mind than my the model I used.

Comment: That's so smart! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I get $\frac{0+2\sqrt 2 + 2} 4 \approx 1.207$ as the expected distance.  The first step moves you to distance $1$ from the origin.  The next step goes back to the origin with probability $1/4$, goes sideways with probability $1/2$, and goes in the same direction with probability $1/4$.

I suppose the discrepancy between what I calculate and what you report is due to Monte Carlo sampling error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are describing a walk on a two dimensional grid.

First step in any direction.  Second step has four choices (assume equally probable), left, right, forward, and backward.   The four eqiproable distances from start are $ \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2},2,0$.  The average is $1..2071$